# How to provide multiple exit codes for the "--stop-exit-codes" flag with PM2

Tags: python, pm2

I have been using PM2 for some of my personal projects and have been making use of the "--stop-exit-codes" flag to stop on a certain kind of exit code that I have made, but I would also like to stop restart on 0 now. I know that I could make the exit code for the other function also 0, fixing my issue, but I would like to have multiple if that is possible. I know that I could do it via a CONFIG file but I need to do it via the CLI since the arguments are very malleable that I would like to pass. I have looked through the source code [here](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/tree/master/lib) and have not been able to find the specific parser. As of right now I have tried spaces and commas as separators, and passing the flag twice (which just overwrites it). The documentation for this topic has not been brought up anywhere that I can find. Thanks for any help that you can provide.

edit: The language the scripts are in is Python. I just realized I did not include that though it should not make a difference.